# ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

not sure what to do. i keep getting this message "ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64" I am unsure if it has to do with my process but I have a Mac M1 chip for my laptop.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It can happen when you unlink your `AppDelegate` from your app's target (it happened to me due to some bad conflict resolution). It also can mean that for some other reason `@main` attribute disappeared from your `AppDelegate`'s class.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your project and target.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hit this error while Archiving.

After some trial-and-error I discovered that this terribly confusing error was actually caused by my deleting `Preview Content/Preview.xcassets`

Restoring the folder + catalogue (and correcting the reference in Build Settings) resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It means, you missed your app file. Remove the reference and drag it also tick the project.